# Convert Azure Computer VIsion Read response to MergeText skill related in Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cognitive-search, azure-cognitive-services

Raw `Read` response from `Azure Computer Vision` looks like this:

```
{
  "status": "succeeded",
  "createdDateTime": "2021-04-08T21:56:17.6819115+00:00",
  "lastUpdatedDateTime": "2021-04-08T21:56:18.4161316+00:00",
  "analyzeResult": {
    "version": "3.2",
    "readResults": [
      {
        "page": 1,
        "angle": 0,
        "width": 338,
        "height": 479,
        "unit": "pixel",
        "lines": [
          {
            "boundingBox": [
              25,
              14
            ],
            "text": "NOTHING",
            "appearance": {
              "style": {
                "name": "other",
                "confidence": 0.971
              }
            },
            "words": [
              {
                "boundingBox": [
                  27,
                  15
                ],
                "text": "NOTHING",
                "confidence": 0.994
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Copied from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-rest-api#examine-the-response)

I want to create `custom skill` in `Azure Cognitive Search` that are not using `VisionSkill` but my own Azure Functions that will use `Computer vision` client in code.

The problem is, that to pass input to `Text.MergeSkill`:

```
{
      "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.MergeSkill",
      "description": "Create merged_text, which includes all the textual representation of each image inserted at the right location in the content field.",
      "context": "/document",
      "insertPreTag": " ",
      "insertPostTag": " ",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "name":"text",
          "source": "/document/content"
        },
        {
          "name": "itemsToInsert", 
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/text"
        },
        {
          "name":"offsets", 
          "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/contentOffset"
        }
      ],
      "outputs": [
        {
          "name": "mergedText", 
          "targetName" : "merged_text"
        }
      ]
    }
```

i need to convert `Read` output to form that returns `OcrSkill` from custom skills. That response must look like this:

```
{
  "text": "Hello World. -John",
  "layoutText":
  {
    "language" : "en",
    "text" : "Hello World.",
    "lines" : [
      {
        "boundingBox":
        [ {"x":10, "y":10}, {"x":50, "y":10}, {"x":50, "y":30},{"x":10, "y":30}],
        "text":"Hello World."
      },
    ],
    "words": [
      {
        "boundingBox": [ {"x":110, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":30},{"x":110, "y":30}],
        "text":"Hello"
      },
      {
        "boundingBox": [ {"x":110, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":10}, {"x":150, "y":30},{"x":110, "y":30}],
        "text":"World."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And i copied it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-ocr#sample-text-and-layouttext-output)

My question is, how to convert `boundingBox` parameter from [Read Computer Vision endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/quickstarts-sdk/client-library?tabs=visual-studio&pivots=programming-language-rest-api) to form that `Text.MergeSkill` accept? Do we really need to do that or we just can pass `Read` response to `Text.MergeSkill` diffrently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built in [OCRSkill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-ocr) calls the Cognitive Services Computer Vision Read API for certain languages, and it handles the merging of the text for you via the 'text' output. If at all possible, I would strongly suggest you use this skill instead of writing a custom one.

If you must write a custom skill and merge the output text yourself, per [the MergeSkill documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-textmerger), the 'text' and 'offsets' inputs are optional. Meaning that you should just be able to directly pass the text from the individual Read API output objects to the MergeSkill via the 'itemsToInsert' input if you just need a way to merge those outputs together into one large text. This would make your skillset look something like this (not tested to know for sure), assuming you are still using the built in AzureSearch image extraction and your custom skill outputs the exact payload that the Read API returns that you shared above.

```
{
    "skills": [
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Custom.WebApiSkill",
            "description": "Custom skill that calls Cognitive Services Computer Vision Read API",
            "uri": "<your custom skill uri>",
            "batchSize": 1,
            "context": "/document/normalized_images/*",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "image",
                    "source": "/document/normalized_images/*"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "readAPIOutput"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Skills.Text.MergeSkill",
            "description": "Create merged_text, which includes all the textual representation of each image inserted at the right location in the content field.",
            "context": "/document",
            "insertPreTag": "",
            "insertPostTag": "\n",
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "name": "itemsToInsert",
                    "source": "/document/normalized_images/*/readAPIOutput/analyzeResult/readResults/*/lines/*/text"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "name": "mergedText",
                    "targetName": "merged_text"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

However, if you need to guarantee that the text appears in the correct order based on the bounding boxes, you will likely need to write a custom solution to calculate the positions and recombine the text yourself. Hence the suggestion to use our built in solution in the OCRSkill if at all possible.

Comment: So the question is, why Computer Vision not returning offset like `OCR skill` from azure search? How is it diffrent can u explain?

Comment: The contentOffset comes from when we extract and normalized embedded images from files from your data source. It is not provided by the OCRSkill. Basically it means if you provide us a document with native text and embedded images, we give you the offset of where we extracted those images from within the native text so that you can use the MergeSkill to merge it back into one text in the correct order later on. This is discussed in the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/cognitive-search-concept-image-scenarios#about-normalized-images

Comment: Thanks for clarify this. So i am returning from my custom webapi skill (that are working on Read API from Azure CV) only `text`. Based on your comment i dont need `boundingBox` (that i need to calculate it myself in my scenerio) i only need `contentOffset` that comes from `normalizedImage`. But when i put `contentOffset` back to `MergeText skill` OCRed data from images comes not in the place where i put it but in the end of page. Why is it happening?

Comment: I just created second question in this topic, take a look please! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556482/azure-search-why-ocred-text-is-not-merged-in-correct-order